# Uploading excel file Laravel

Tags: php, excel, laravel

I try to upload an excel file with a form in Laravel but I have the issue : 
**Call to a member function store() on a non-object**

Here is my code :

```
{!! Form::open(['route' => 'choixcol']) !!}
  <div class="col-md-4">
     {!! Form::file('data', '', ['id' =>  'file', 'class' =>  'form-control']) !!}
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-8">
     {!! Form::submit("Utiliser ce fichier", array('class' => 'btn btn-info')) !!}
  </div>

{!! Form::close() !!}
```

And my function in my Controller:

```
public function upload(Request $request) {
    $path = $request->file('data')->store('data');
    return view('mesures.index');
}
```

How to solve it please?

**EDIT :**

In my $request I have :

```
Request {#37 ▼
  #json: null
  #sessionStore: null
  #userResolver: Closure {#231 ▶}
  #routeResolver: Closure {#248 ▶}
  +attributes: ParameterBag {#39 ▶}
  +request: ParameterBag {#38 ▼
  #parameters: array:2 [▼
   "_token" => "6IPVFkzu8o2jH244y0BwJEqKDqfWrt5pKwMS7Pls"
   "data" => "99081D_Pesee2016.xlsx"
  ]
}
+query: ParameterBag {#45 ▶}
+server: ServerBag {#42 ▶}
+files: FileBag {#41 ▶}
+cookies: ParameterBag {#40 ▶}
+headers: HeaderBag {#43 ▶}
#content: null
#languages: null
#charsets: null
#encodings: null
#acceptableContentTypes: null
#pathInfo: "/mesures/choix"
#requestUri: "/mesures/choix"
#baseUrl: ""
#basePath: null
#method: "POST"
#format: null
#session: Store {#205 ▶}
#locale: null
#defaultLocale: "en"
}
```

I think I just get the name of the file but not the file directly...

Answer (score 0):

The error is saying that `file('data')` is not an object in this case.

I would Log the `$request` array like `Log::debug($request);` and see what you have access to.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/requests#storing-uploaded-files

Comment: I edit my question. In my $request I just have the name of the file that's probably why I can't save it but I don't understand how to do...

Comment: glad you figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

**I found the solution**, it was very simple : I forgot to set 'files'=>true to my form !